# Converting Multiple Sprite Images into One

Tags: swift, image, sprite-kit, sprite

In an app I'm testing out, I'm using a gradient image as a background (590kb in size). I have the ability of breaking this image into 0.5 pixel vertical strips (19kb) and having this image repeat itself (1334 times) to create the same larger background image. I have 20 different background images total so the app will be 11.8mb vs 380kb in storage usage.

I don't like the idea of having 1334 sprites, but I do like the idea of using less storage. So, is there a way of flatting the 1334 images into one sprite? Not sure if this make sense, but any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You can create an array of files and save it as an NSData file.

Comment: You might want to simply test this. Have your scene show the number of nodes, frames-per-second and draw calls and see how performance varies with lots of small sprites vs fewer bigger ones. Alternatively, just accept that 11.8Mb of background images isn't really that much.

Comment: Thanks Steve, yeah I knew having 1334 sprite was not a good idea, thats why I was hoping there would be a way of converting all of those images into one (basically creating a new .png file at run time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use image at all if you want to have a gradient. Take a look at this:

```
 let context = CIContext()
        if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CILinearGradient")
        {
            filter.setDefaults()

            let startColor = CIColor(color: .gray)
            let endColor = CIColor(color: .purple)
            let startVector = CIVector(x: frame.width, y: 0)
            let endVector = CIVector(x: frame.width, y: frame.height)

            filter.setValue(startVector, forKey: "inputPoint0")
            filter.setValue(endVector, forKey: "inputPoint1")
            filter.setValue(startColor, forKey: "inputColor0")
            filter.setValue(endColor, forKey: "inputColor1")


            if let outputImage = filter.outputImage {

                if let  croppedImage = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: frame.size)){

                    let background  = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(cgImage: croppedImage))

                    addChild(background)
                    background.zPosition = -20

                }

            }

        }
```

Repeating an image horizontally or vertically to achieve the same effect is possible. That would require creating texture from a container node using something like [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skview/1519994-texture). Still, IMO, you may want skip that and do gradient programatically. And certainly I would stay away of having many nodes which act as a background. That would be silly :)

Comment: Thanks Whirlwind! I spend hours yesterday trying to figure out how to create the gradient effect programmatically and use it as a texture for a sprite. Everything I read online yesterday seemed very complicated, but what you have provided is easy to understand and works like a treat.